# Comparing a Date object to null, what happens?

Tags: javascript, date, coercion

I came across the fact, that when you compare dates in JavaScript, the following happens:

```
$ new Date() > null
> true

$ new Date() > undefined
> false
```

I was wondering, what exactly happens *under the hood*, that leads to this behavior.

Comment: Automatic type coercion. `null` is coerced to `0`, `undefinend` is coerced to `NaN` before comparison.

Comment: This is not possible. You just can not assign it to null

Comment: @Teemu dont you agree with me? Date can not and should not be assigned null. if you dont agree you can search it.

Comment: @khan Umh ... There's no assignments in the OP's code. And JS is a weakly typed language ...

Comment: @Teemu maybe you are right Js is weakly typed language but still you cant just null the date. Yes there is not assignments but what the code says ? null the date ! right? My point is null for Date  is not gonna show you any error warnings neither any result other then undefined.

Comment: @khan The code doesn't "null the date", it just creates a new date, and __compares__ it to __`null`__ and to __`undefined`__, no assignments, no nullifying, just date objects and automatic type coercion of `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @Teemu I understand what you are saying I must admit you are quite right. But I still dont understand comparing null to date and undefined does not make any sense why would developer do that even though the out come is pretty much obvious.

Comment: @khan Probably not on purpose, but in a case a date is compared against a variable which contains `null` or `undefined`, it is good to know what the result is going to be.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge @Teemu this is the first time I learned something from deleted question LOL.